# Свернуть таблицу по столбцам (для мобильной версии)

Tags: javascript, css3

Есть таблица, хочу ее свернуть по столбцам (Операционная система) во вкладки.
Как здесь https://www.shopify.com/pricing

```css
td{width:100px;text-align:center;}
.hh,th{font-weight:bold;color:magenta;}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="hh">OS</th>
        <th>Windows</th>
        <th>Linux</th>
        <th>iOs</th>
        <th>Android</th>
        <th>etc</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="hh">Option 1</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hh">Option 2</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hh">Option 3</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hh">Option 4</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Буду благодарна за любую подсказку!

[image: Пример мобильной версии, свернули 3 столбца в 3 соотв. вкладки]

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать через data-, думаю для данного варианта неплохо подойдет.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) 
{
    table thead {
      display: none;
    }

    table tr {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      display: block;
      border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    }

    table td {
      display: block;
      text-align: right;
      font-size: 13px;
      border-bottom: 1px dotted red;
    }

    table td:last-child {
      border-bottom: 0;
    }

    table td:before {
      content: attr(data-title);
      float: left;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: bold;
      min-width: 100px;
      text-align: left;
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="hh">OS</th>
        <th>Windows</th>
        <th>Linux</th>
        <th>iOs</th>
        <th>Android</th>
        <th>etc</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td data-title="OS" class="hh">Option 1</td>
        <td data-title="Windows">value</td>
        <td data-title="Linux">value</td>
        <td data-title="iOs">value</td>
        <td data-title="Android">value</td>
        <td data-title="etc">value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-title="OS" class="hh">Option 1</td>
        <td data-title="Windows">value</td>
        <td data-title="Linux">value</td>
        <td data-title="iOs">value</td>
        <td data-title="Android">value</td>
        <td data-title="etc">value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-title="OS" class="hh">Option 1</td>
        <td data-title="Windows">value</td>
        <td data-title="Linux">value</td>
        <td data-title="iOs">value</td>
        <td data-title="Android">value</td>
        <td data-title="etc">value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-title="OS" class="hh">Option 1</td>
        <td data-title="Windows">value</td>
        <td data-title="Linux">value</td>
        <td data-title="iOs">value</td>
        <td data-title="Android">value</td>
        <td data-title="etc">value</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```